# Javascript Button only works for my login in sandbox,for others it throws error

Tags: javascript, custom-button, custom, list-button

I have a weird issue in my sand box.
I had wrote a javascript custom button to open a tab in primary tab.But the weird  thing is this code only works in my Login only,for others in the same sandbox it throws error

> Unable to Access Page
>   You are missing information needed by the page
>   you have attempted to access. If you believe this is an error, please
>   refresh your screen. If the error persists, please report it to our
>   Customer Support team and provide the URL of the page you were
>   requesting as well as any other related information.

Javascript code :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/xdomain/xdomain.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/33.0/integration.js")} 

var url = "{!$Setup.Product_Complaints_ObjectId__c.ObjectID__c}"; 
if (typeof(srcSelf) == 'function') { 

sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent='+url+'&q_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=/a6z/o&save_new_url=/a6z/e?retURL=/a6z/o', true, 'New Product Complaint', openSuccess, 'salesforceTab');
var openSuccess = function openSuccess(result) {};  
}else{ 
window.open("/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01IM0000000A31h&q_lkid={!Case.Id}&retURL=/a6z/o&save_new_url=/a6z/e?retURL=/a6z/o","_blank"); 
}
```

In If part i fetch the id from a custom setting (didn't work for other user included admins in sandbox except me),in else part id is hardcoded (Works for all the users in sandbox).

Comment: Issue may be this hard coded value `ent=01IM0000000A31h`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. actually there is no problem with this id,problem is with custom setting.

Comment: Suggest you manually enter the URL when logged in as someone else and diagnose that problem: perhaps it is something like a record type not being available to other users.